# Adding attendees to a Google calendar event

Tags: vb.net, google-calendar-api

I have VB application that creates events in a Google calendar. It is the v3 library.

It supports pop up reminder notifications but now I want to support email notifications.

I did more research and came across a help page that indicated email notifications can be sent to the event attendees.

But I can't find a tutorial explaining how to add attendees to a new event.

Advice appreciated. Will repost if this is wrong place.

Comment: This is a bit vague without some code showing what you have already tried. I suspect that the lack of examples points to something trivial that just does not seem obvious at the moment. If you post your code, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it..

```
Private Sub AddAttendeeToEvent(calEvent As [Event], name As String, email As String, comment As String, responseStatus as String)
    Dim attendee As New EventAttendee
    attendee.DisplayName = name
    attendee.Email = email
    attendee.Comment = comment
    attendee.ResponseStatus = responseStatus
    calEvent.Attendees.Add(attendee)
End Sub
```

You can of course include other properties if you wish. Dont forget that `.ResponseStatus" strings are limited to "declined", "accepted", "tentative" or "needsAction"

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much.